# The program '[1684] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450750 (0x80008082)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-functions

Trying to debug an Azure function .NET STANDARD 2.0 locally. Using Visual Studio 2017 CE. Stuff worked yesterday wonder what have gone wrong. Uninstalled all NET CORE SDK and put back the 2.1.201. Found other solutions about Core 1.1 but no luck with them. When debugging the console shuts down right away and only leaves this error message

```
The program '[1684] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450750 (0x80008082).
```

Comment: So you have installed .net core sdk `2.1.300` and things worked once, but today your function failed to start?

Comment: I think I have been running on 2.1.201 all the time. Had some others installed as well, removed them all and put back 2.1.201

Comment: Are you on VS 15.8 (preview)? There is a known issue https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md#known-issues

Comment: I am on version 15.7.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

I went to a wrong place before. This problem is not caused by missing .Net Core 2.1. It may be related to `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`(on VS menus, Tools>Extensions and Update).

From version of `15.0.40502.0`, the extension consumes a feed which keeps templates, build tools, and the runtime up to date whenever there is a change made in the service.

See `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.2.2\manifest.json`.

```
"CliEntrypointPath": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.2.2\\cli\\func.exe"
```

In VS, entry of 2.x cli was always `func.dll` before. Eliminating the requirement of .Net Core 2.1 for cli 2.0.1-beta.31(host 2.0.11888), a self contained version(x86) is pushed to VS. Its entry is `func.exe`.

If the entry remains to be `func.dll` on your x64 platform, error will occur due to running x86 `func.dll` with x64 dotnet.

Digging deeper, we can see the following error message

```
Failed to load the dll from [C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.2.2\cli\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.2.2\cli\]
```

**Solution**

If your `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools` is `15.0.40617`, just change the entry to `func.exe`. Then restart VS(necessary step).

If your version is lower, I recommend you to update to `15.0.40617`. After update, delete `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools`, then create a new Azure Function project, wait at the create dialog for VS to download new cli and template.

[image]
    After a while, we can see the tip change to

[image]

Comment: I re installed Visual Studio just before reading your answer. That sorted it out

Comment: @Jepzen So things works now? Do you mind checking what's your `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools` or .net core sdk version to verify whether I am right?

Comment: Yes it is working now. Under AzureFunctionsTools\Releases I have 1.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.2. dotnet --version spits out 2.1.201. Is that enough?

Comment: @Jepzen Yes, reinstall must have updated your `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`. Check it on VS menus, Tools>Extensions and Updates, you may find its version is 15.0.40617.0. This new extension helps you run `2.0.11888` (aka 2.2.2)without .net core 2.1.

Comment: @Jepzen I revert to this version, but VS back to use old function core tools(2.0.1-beta.25). Check cli output when debugging, `[6/29/2018 10:16:42 PM] Starting Host (HostId=xxx, InstanceId=xxx, Version=2.0.11888.0`. if it's `2.0.11651.0`, it means it works by using old function core tools. You'd better update `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools` to consume the latest. If it's `2.0.11888.0`, you can move on since new version works well on your side.

Comment: I upgraded the tools to 15.0.40617.0. deleted the folder and I can still debug. So all good right now. Thanks

Comment: Confirmed changing `func.dll` to `func.exe` in `manifest.json`'s `CliEntrypointPath` entry and restarting VS solved the `An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from` when starting functions.

Answer (score 2):

I had an exactly same issue. I installed .NET Core 2.1 SDK, updated Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools to version 15.0.40617.0 and it still didn't work. I decided to revert Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools to version 15.0.40608.0 and it works! Additionally, I have version 2.1.301 of .NET Core.

Comment: Could you check what's your function host version? See this line output  when debugging, `[6/29/2018 10:16:42 PM] Starting Host (HostId=xxx, InstanceId=xxx, Version=2.0.11888.0, ProcessId=....)`. Version should be `2.0.11888.0` if it does work on latest function core tools. On my side, use `15.0.40608.0` make VS use old `2.0.11651.0`. This version may work for your code, but you will lose many fixes and enhancements in new version.

Comment: As I see it currently works on old function core tools (Host Version=2.0.11651.0). I will check your tips about func.dll -> func.exe later on.

Comment: @JerryLiu I tried your solution and it works. Thanks!